# Boot won't get past auto fsck, any help?

Tags: boot, fsck

I restarted my computer and after an error booting, I got into `initramfs`, from there I did `fsck`, `e2fsck` all the sorts. However `e2fsck` was taking too long so I just forced shut down my pc. Then when I restarted my pc, it just won't get past the auto `fsck`, any help?

EDIT: `fsck` is done, `fsck` isn't doing anything, it goes to a blank screen and then goes back to the `fsck: /dev/sda5 clean` or something along those lines, that isn't the issue.

EDIT 2 for more clarification: After it says clean, it just blanks the screen a bit between black and the `fsck /dev/sda5`, and nothing happens. It doesn't go to login screen.

Comment: Just let `fsck` run and go cook dinner or something.

Comment: Fsck is done, fsck isn't doing anything, it goes to a blank screen and then goes back to the fsck: /dev/sda5 clean or something along those lines, that isn't the issue

Comment: After it reports `clean` does it then proceed to login screen normally?

Comment: No, that's my issue

Comment: Here they recommend just letting it keep looping until it doesn't: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=791788

Comment: `fsck` is just a file-system check... usually required after an unclean shutdown (by force shutdown do you mean you're using SysRq commands to direct the kernel to cleanly shutdown after `sync`, `umount` etc?    I would boot a *live* system and explore for clues, if booting your normal system only boot to runlevel 1 & explore.. (systemd journal, space, command or `apt` history for last good session etc)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue from the display manager, I went into recovery mode by pressing escape in the first few seconds that the pc loads, then chose advanced options then recovery mode, from there I changed my lightdm desktop manager to the default gdm by doing this.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

And from there I used the arrow keys to choose gdm3, and rebooted my computer and it worked.